# Chad Gadya - Who composed it?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, song-poetry

Who composed the Chad Gadya song at the end of the Hagada?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unknown Author.

See [here](http://ohr.edu/holidays/pesach/history/835).