# When was Nirtzah added?

Tags: minhag, history, passover-seder-hagada, song-poetry

The [Rambam's Haggadah](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/3510.htm) and the [Ba'al HaTanya's Haggadah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10502&st=&pgnum=47) lack Nirtzah. @DoubleAA [quotes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81598/mayim-achronim-at-the-pesach-seder#comment249798_81598) a version of the Simanim poem in which the order concludes with Hallel, as well. Also note the discussion [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70278/why-dont-chabad-say-chasal-sidur-pesach) regarding various mesoros about Chasal Siddur Pesach.

Many of the piyutim that comprise Nirtzah are of unknown origin - note [Echad Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14343/who-composed-the-piyut-echad-mi-yodeya) and [Chad Gadya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6531/chad-gadya-who-composed-it). My question is not about who wrote them. My question is when Nirtzah was widely accepted as a part of the Seder - that is to say, when were these songs tacked on to the end of the Seder?

Related: [What is Nirtzah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14345/9682)

Comment: Do you mean when were songs sung after the Seder or when those songs started being called a section called Nirtza? The former probably happened a long time ago, while the latter is probably pretty recent.

Comment: @DoubleAA The former

Comment: It seems reasonable the Rambam also had songs at the end. He just didn't record them in his Hagadah since they aren't Halakha (like he never mentions specific Shabbat Zemirot in Hilkhot Shabbat). You can't prove anything from Haggadot that don't include stuff like that.

Comment: I thought that just the paragraph "Chasal Sidur Pesach ..." constituted Nirtza.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is that better, on both counts?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok That is just [a conclusion from a Piyut from the repetition of the Amida from Shabbat HaGadol](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42979&st=&pgnum=655) (as is [the "Vayhi Bachatzi Halayla" poem](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42979&st=&pgnum=651)). Nirtza isn't a thing that is constituted by any particular set of words. Just people sing songs after they finish. People sing songs on Shabbat too.

Comment: Although not in any way a complete answer to the question, just wanted to point out that the Ba'al HaTanya v'Hashulchan Aruch is following his general pattern; his siddur includes very few zemiros, piyuttim, yotzros, krovos etc., due to Halachic  (Hefsek: שו"ע או"ח סח:א וכן הוא שיטת הרמב"ם והגר"א) and Kabbalistic reasons. (האר"י שער הכוונות ריש ענין נוסח התפלה, מ"א ריש סי' סח, שו"ע הרב סח:ב), though the reason of Hefsek would obviously not apply in the OP's case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R. Yosef Zvi Rimon's book *Hagaddah MiMekorah* pins the songs of *nirtzah* to the end of the fifteenth century. He relates the following:

> In all of the haggadah texts of the Ge'onim...and Rishonim, none of the piyyutim that we say during *nirtzah* appear, and the haggadah ends after *nishmat*. However, by the time of the *Rishonim* of *Ashkenaz* (what is now Germany), some began to appear. *Tashbetz Katan* mentions the piyyut of "*Ki lo na'eh*"...*Leket Yosher* [written by R. Yosef b. Moshe (1423-1490)] mentions the piyyutim of "*az rov nissim*," "*ometz gevuratecha*," "*ki lo na'eh*" and "*adir bimeluchah*." Over the years, seven piyyutim entered the Ashkenazic haggadot (and gradually, some of them entered the Sephardic haggadot): "*chasal siddur Pesach,*" "*az rov nissim,*" "*ometz gevuratecha,*" "*adir bimeluchah,*" "*adir hu,*" "*echad mi yode'a*" and "*chad gadya*".